# Postgresql: More than 100 parameters for execute format query

Tags: postgresql

I am executing a SQL query using execute format which requires multiple number of variables to be passed as a parameter. Over here my query needs lot of symbols such as : `'%' and ','`

Hence my query has been so big that it is exceeding the limit of 100 parameters. So is there a way to include `'%' and ','` in the query itself rather than passing it as a parameter.

Query:

```
 execute format('CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW %I AS 
        SELECT id,
               (select count(*) from friends bob where (i.name ilike any (string_to_array(replace( concat(%L,bob.keywords,%L),%L,%L),%L)) or 
i.description ilike any (string_to_array(replace( concat(%L,bob.keywords,%L),%L,%L),%L)) or
 i.additional_info ilike any (string_to_array(replace( concat(%L,bob.keywords,%L),%L,%L),%L)) or 
i.eventful_category ilike any (string_to_array(replace( concat(%L,bob.keywords,%L),%L,%L),%L)) or
 i.other_category ilike any (string_to_array(replace( concat(%L,bob.keywords,%L),%L,%L),%L)) )) as friend_bob
from events i ','FrienView','%','%',',','%,%',',','%','%',',','%,%',',','%','%',',','%,%',',','%','%',',','%,%',',','%','%',',','%,%',',')
```

Comment: How and where are you creating your query strings?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Have updated my question with the query. This is just the part of the query, further it will include similar type of query to generate more columns as needed

Comment: Query created in MOUNT DOOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT)

> The `concat`, `concat_ws` and `format` functions are variadic, so it is
>   possible to pass the values to be concatenated or formatted as an
>   array marked with the `VARIADIC` keyword

You can use `ARRAY` to overcome the limitation, eg:
prepare:

```
with n as (select generate_series(1,101,1) g) 
  select $$SELECT format('$$||string_agg('%s',',')||$$',$$||string_agg(g::text,',')||')' 
  from n;
```

run:

```
SELECT format('%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s',1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101);
```

> ERROR:  cannot pass more than 100 arguments to a function

as array:

```
SELECT format('%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s'
,VARIADIC ARRAY[1, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101]);
```

> 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101
>   (1 row)

**But I would stop and think here - do you really want to pass 100 arguments?..**

Comment: interesting, is there a similar strategy that can be used with jsonb_build_object, which takes mixed argument types... `apparently  type "pg_catalog.anyelement[]" does not exist`